# How to properly make a rest api call to positionStack in Angular with an ng-autocomplete address input, and debounce it

Tags: angular, autocomplete, debouncing

I'm trying, for the first time, to implement an autocomplete address form in Angular 9.
I use [positionstack rest api](https://positionstack.com/documentation) to retrieve addresses, and [angular-ng-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete) to display the results under the text input.
I manage to call the api and to get the results, even to display it, but i don't think i am doing it correctly cause i have several warnings and errors appearing.

And lastly i would like to debounce the rest api call. So far it is executed on each key stroke, but i can't manage to make it works.

Here is the response object that i get from the api :

```
"data": [
        {
            "latitude": 45.136054,
            "longitude": 5.711749,
            "type": "street",
            "name": "Avenue Général de Gaulle",
            "number": null,
            "postal_code": null,
            "street": "Avenue Général de Gaulle",
            "confidence": 0.8,
            "region": "Isère",
            "region_code": "IS",
            "county": null,
            "locality": null,
            "administrative_area": "Le Pont-De-Claix",
            "neighbourhood": null,
            "country": "France",
            "country_code": "FRA",
            "continent": "Europe",
            "label": "Avenue Général de Gaulle, Le Pont-De-Claix, France"
        },...
]
```

Here is my html template

```html
  <ng-autocomplete
    [data]="addresses"
    [searchKeyword]="keyword"
    [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
    [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate"
    (inputChanged)="onChange($event)"
    placeHolder="Recherchez votre adresse">
  </ng-autocomplete>

  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
    <a [innerHTML]="item?.label"></a>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
    <div [innerHTML]="notFound"></div>
  </ng-template>
```

and my typescripts classes

```js
export class AutocompleteAddressComponent {

  keyword: string;
  public addresses;

  constructor(private mapService: MapService) { }

  onChange(event: any) {
    this.addresses = [];
    if (event.length > 3 ) {
      this.mapService.getCoordinates(event).subscribe(
        response => {
          this.addresses = response.data; <- WARNING: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Object
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

The map service method is a simple get with query parameters.

```js
  public getCoordinates(query: string) {
    console.log('Sending request');
    query = query.trim();
    const options = query ?
      {
        params: new HttpParams()
          .set('access_key', environment.positionstack_apikey)
          .set('query', query)
          .set('limit', '10')
          .set('output', 'json')
      } : {};

    return this.httpClient.get(
      this.baseUrl + '/forward',
      options
    );
  }
```

I have a warning in IntelliJ when i try to affect the result of the call to my addresses object (that i will later transform to a model). and i'm getting error in the web browser console :

```
core.js:6185 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at HighlightPipe.transform (angular-ng-autocomplete.js:1529)
    at pureFunction3Internal (core.js:36519)
    at Module.ɵɵpipeBind3 (core.js:36698)
    at AutocompleteComponent_li_10_div_2_Template (angular-ng-autocomplete.js:92)
```

the result list id displaying, but it is not very stable, so i'm probably doing something wrong.

Lastly i tried to add a debouncing method to the rest call using subject and observable, but it doesn't trigger the call anymore.

My modified class:

```js
export class AutocompleteAddressComponent implements OnInit{
  result$: Observable<any>;
  subject = new Subject<string>();

  public addresses;
  keyword: string;

  constructor(private mapService: MapService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.result$ = this.subject.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      map(searchText => this.mapService.getCoordinates(searchText).subscribe(
        result => console.log(result)
      ))
    );
  }

  onChange(keyword: any) {
    this.addresses = [];
    if (keyword.length > 3 ) {
      this.subject.next(keyword);
    }
  }
}
```

If the question is not clear enough i will make a stackblitz !
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, when digging more, i found a very much simpler way to do everything as i want thanks to [this tutorial](https://www.freakyjolly.com/autocomplete-using-angular-ng-autocomplete-package-tutorial-by-example/#.Xuh96WgzaUk).

In fact everything is properly handled by ng-autocomplete out of the box.
My main problem was that i didn't valuate the 'keyword' variable with the name of the field on which i want to search.

So here is the full solution with the rest api call to a map service, the debounce time and a minimum query length that are handled too by ng-autocomplete, and on select the creation of a model object with the properties that i need.

Html template :

```html
<div class="ng-autocomplete">
  <ng-autocomplete 
    [data]="addresses"
    [searchKeyword]="keyword"
    (selected)='selectEvent($event)'
    (inputChanged)='getServerResponse($event)'
    (inputCleared)="searchCleared()"
    [debounceTime]="300"
    [isLoading]="isLoadingResult"
    [minQueryLength]="3"
    [itemTemplate]="itemTemplate"
    [notFoundTemplate]="notFoundTemplate"
    placeHolder="Rechercher une adresse...">
  </ng-autocomplete>

  <ng-template #itemTemplate let-item>
    <a [innerHTML]="item.label"></a>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template #notFoundTemplate let-notFound>
    Aucun résultat !
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

component.ts file :

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MapService} from '../service/map.service';
import {AddressModel} from '../model/AddressModel';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete.component.css']
})
export class AutocompleteAddressComponent {

  address: AddressModel;
  addresses: any;
  keyword = 'label';
  isLoadingResult: boolean;

  constructor(private mapService: MapService) {
  }

  getServerResponse(event) {
    this.isLoadingResult = true;
    this.mapService.getCoordinates(event).subscribe(
      (result: any) => {
        this.addresses = result.data;
        this.isLoadingResult = false;
      }
    );
  }

  selectEvent(event: any) {
    this.address = new AddressModel(
      event.latitude,
      event.longitude,
      event.label
    );
  }

  searchCleared() {
    console.log('searchCleared');
    this.addresses = [];
  }
}
```

map service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MapService {

  private baseUrl: string = environment.map_url;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getCoordinates(query: string) {
    query = query.trim();
    const options = query ?
      {
        params: new HttpParams()
          .set('access_key', environment.positionstack_apikey)
          .set('query', query)
          .set('limit', '10')
          .set('output', 'json')
      } : {};

    return this.httpClient.get(
      this.baseUrl + '/forward',
      options
    );
  }
}
```